# Rails - generate Scaffold with Table Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've started learning Ruby last week, and I've started learning Rails today, so bear with me.
I see that Rails come with generators that allow you to generate models/controllers or even model+controller+views bundle as 'scaffold'. This is what I am interested in.

However, I have a question. How do I set database options of the column?

eg. To generate a users table I would do:

```
rails g scaffold users uuid:binary name:string email:string password:binary registered_on:date number:integer default:string
```

Now what if I'm integrity freak and am not happy by having validation just in model/controller, but want to do database level limitations as well.
What if I want `email` to be 50 characters max, and `number` to Auto-Increment and neither of all fields is allowed to be NULL and `default` field must have a default of 'foo'. Is there any way to pass these requirements to generator command?

I know its possible to set these options in .rb file that is used in rake db:migrate, however it would be easier to just pass values in with 1 command.

Comment: do not use 'default' or 'is_default' as a column name.  This can cause  issues depending on which type of database you're using.  Another one as a just in case:   It's also not a good idea to use 'locked' or 'is_locked'.

Comment: thanks, I usually stay away from names like this, I just couldn't find a more original name for that column at time of writing.

Answer (score 13):

At least some things are available, like string length, but not sure about the others.

```
rails g scaffold users email:string{50}
```

Comment: Best practice says your default values go into your migration files. As shown by Dave Newton you can set some default values in the generate method, this will set the default value in the migration file it generates.

Comment: @Dogweather I don't even remember how I found out about this in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use **type modifiers** between curly braces, example:

   ```
   rails generate migration AddDetailsToProducts price:decimal{5,2}
   ```

   More info: [migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)
2. Use scaffold and obtain generic migration files. And, as you mentioned, do the customizations in there. This files are found in `db/migrate`.

After you are done customizing the fields, don't forget to do a `rake db:migrate`.